# Android: How to start contacts for eMail?

Tags: android, email, contacts

this Intent opens the Contacts, containing entries with address information only:

```
Intent getContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI);
```

Now I was trying to use this pattern to filter for contacts containing an eMail:

```
Intent getContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI);
```

But this excepts (no action_pick for intent or so)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you can not with the default Contacts app: the default Contacts app registers this Intent filter (see line 165 in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml#165):

```
<intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                 <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact" />
                 <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/person" />
                 <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/phone_v2" />
                 <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/phone" />
                 <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/postal-address_v2" />
                 <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/postal-address" />
             </intent-filter>
```

So it is able to respond to the postal address `ACTION_PICK` intents, but not to email address `ACTION_PICK` intents.

If you want to do the email address pick you will need to create your own Activity that gets a Cursor from the Contacts provider that only displays users with email addresses and shows that in a ListView for the user to pick.

Comment: @Femi which api supports vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2 as a mime type?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      public void readcontact(){
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }
        }
```

Comment: this throws an exception `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK typ=vnd.android.cursor.dir/email }`